# Can a 3rd Party SDK Embedded in iOS App Run Code If the App Never Calls Any Method on the SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook

It is being reported that the Facebook SDK, when embedded in an app, will run code on app startup ... even if the app never calls any method on the SDK. See [this blog post](https://rambo.codes/posts/2020-05-07-the-big-facebook-crash?utm_campaign=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly&utm_medium=web&utm_source=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly%2BIssue%2B455). Is that even possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Objective-C runtime calls the static [`load`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418815-load?language=objc) method on linked frameworks when an app launches.

In the case you are referring to, some code called from `load` was causing the crash.

The `load` function is not called automatically in frameworks written in Swift.

Comment: Thank you, paulw11. Perfect answer. Bonus point for drawing the distinction between ObjC and Swift.